# Salt-Stack does watch imply require

Tags: salt-stack

We have the following salt state, does the watch imply a require?  Or is the rule best written this way?

```
"celery-worker:":
  supervisord.running:
    - update: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery-worker.conf
      - pkg: ingestion
    - require:
      - file: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery-worker.conf
      - pkg: ingestion
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to specify the `require` for the file and the pkg again. `watch` implies require too.

```
celery-worker:
  supervisord.running:
    - update: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery-worker.conf
      - pkg: ingestion
```